# Django using AJAX or Angular

Tags: django, ajax, angular, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building a blog where users can post and comment using Django, now there is a scenario that I have posts being display on my user page. Using Django for adding a comment it will redirect user to another page. How can I write this using AJAX or AngularJs? I am new to Angular and Ajax and I only need this function specifically.

I appreciate all your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I give you link, you follow that if you will got error then put on same  question lete know link[ajax request](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Answer (score 0):

i am new with Django too.but Django Using MVT that means you can use everything in your template and there is no Limits even React or VueJs. 
so you can use both.